# OAuth unsupported_grant_type

Tags: php, post, curl, oauth

I'm trying to exchange OAuth code with authorization token via curl. Server API documentation says, that I should send POST data, and that I'm doing:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    // return result
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);    // disallow redirection
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);           // timeout 5s
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);            // OAuth access token url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);              // send via POST

// I have prepared query arguments as an array $args
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($args));

// Turning on some debug info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);

// Executing curl
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

The problem is in server response. I'm always getting OAuth error: **unsupported_grant_type**. All documentation sources says that argument grant_type must be set to "authorization_code" value (in all cases on this OAuth step), but anyway it's not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Is this for SalesForce OAuth?

If so, they required Content-Type and Content-Length to be set, for example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-length: ".strlen($params)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since (according to the comment) `http_build_query($args)` returns an array , curl is sending the POST with content type `multipart/form-data` (see the [docs for curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt)). The OAuth server probably wants `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, in which case `http_build_query` needs to return a urlencoded string like `para1=val1&para2=val2&...`.

Comment: http_build_query($args) can ONLY return a string; it _receives_ the array.  The function is not built to do otherwise. [http_build_query ( mixed $query_data [, string $numeric_prefix [, string $arg_separator [, int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738 ]]] ) : string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your generic CURL requests should be customized with

1. Form Data Params / Query Params,
2. Content Type

Answer (score 0):

Following is a working code in that returns Authentication token using client_and client_secret from google servers.

```
`tok_url:OAuth Token url, Auth_token: authentication token returned from google servers when cust_id and cust_secret are passed`

int get_refresh_token(char* tok_url,char* auth_token,char*cust_id,char*cust_secret)
{
    CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
    char data[1024]="\0";
    strcat(data,"code=");
    strcat(data,auth_token);
    strcat(data,"&client_id=");
    strcat(data,cust_id);
    strcat(data,"&client_secret=");
    strcat(data,cust_secret);
    strcat(data,"&redirect_uri=");
    strcat(data,"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
    strcat(data,"&grant_type=authorization_code");
    puts(data);


  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* get a curl handle */ 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
       just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
       data. */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, tok_url);
    /* Now specify the POST data */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();
}
```